# Is there a way to expose an AWS lambda layer publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to understand the compliance aspect of the lambda layer. Can it be exposed publicly by design or not?

Comment: It would help if you'd add a bit more context and background around your question so it's clearer what you do understand and don't understand and what the reason behind your question is.

Comment: What do you mean by "compliance aspect"?

Comment: Best practice - wise. I think it is not the best idea to expose your layers, but is it possible to do so?

Comment: API Gateway to Lambda Proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Publish](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverlessrepo/latest/devguide/sharing-lambda-layers.html) your Lambda layer to the [AWS Serverless Application Repository](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/serverlessrepo/), and share it (either publicly or privately).